# Get employees that were active during specific date range

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I get list of active employees who were active in a specific date range (1-JAN-2014 TO 31-MAR-2014)

My table is like
Table:
**employeeheader**

- empid
- firstname
- lastname

**emphistory**

- empid
- begindate
- enddate

If enddate is null that means employee is still active.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM employeeheader
JOIN emphistory ON employeeheader.empid = emphistory.empid
WHERE begindate <= <range_start> AND (enddate is null OR enddate >= <range_end>)
```

This gives all the employees which worked completely during a specific range.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work - I didn't actually test it.

```
where begindate < the day after your end date
and nvl(enddate, sysdate) >= your start date
```

Since oracle dates include the time of day, you want to account for it, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This query can help

```
SELECT * FROM employeeheader
WHERE empid IN
(SELECT empid FROM emphistory
 WHERE (enddate IS NULL OR enddate>= EndDateParameter) 
        AND begindate<=BeginDateParameter)
```