# How to calculate the total numbers of employees available as at a specific day given their date of entry?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have a table in my database called `Employee`.
Assuming it has only 3 columns, namely `EmpID`, `Dept`, `DateOfEntry`, `Date Left`, what would be the `SQL` query syntax that will give the count of employees as at, say, `2017-05-31`

Each row in the table represents a single employee.

Here is how the `Employee` Table stands:

```
EmpId   Dept      DateOfEntry   DateLeft
100     F&B       2015-06-05    2016-01-02
125     Kitchen   2016-02-12    2016-03-10
151     Finance   2018-05-03    NULL
...
```

UPDATE: Apologies for missing the DateLeft column in the above table. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Considering they don't have a leave date, does this mean once they have joined they can never leave?

Comment: @Larnu I'm extremely sorry. Yes, it does have a column for Date Left!! I am updating the question.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? As there is both an entry and an exit date, the query will be very simple. What query have you written? Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Can one employee work for two departments at the same time?

Comment: You still need to add what you've tried. You have enough reputation to know that providing what you tried is really important when asking a question.

Comment: @Larnu. Sorry. I was away from my computer for the last hours. I understand the need for showing efforts in solving the problem. To be honest, I was stuck at the SQL syntax relating to the logic to be implemented. After some research, I did find something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636311/get-employees-that-were-active-during-specific-date-range
But I have not yet given it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the OP isn't going to post their attempt.

This is a very simple query, and with a bit of a Google/Bing/Yahoo you probably would have found the syntax on how to use a `WHERE` clause with Greater Than (`>`) and Less Than (`<`) expressions. Anyway, the answer you want is:

```
DECLARE @Date date;
SET @Date = '20170531';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Employees
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateOfEntry <= @Date
  AND (DateLeft > @Date --I assume that they are no longer emplyed on the day they leave, other use >=
   OR  DateLeft IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want at in single date than try this:

```
select count(EmpID) from employee 
where DateOfEntry>='31-may-2017' and (dateleft is null or dateleft< getdate())
```

Comment: Using the OP's sample data, this would give a result of 0. That doesn't give a result based on what the OP describes.

Comment: it seems to me that there is more data in that table as there is ..... and also his question is at a specific date, that's why I answered in this way

Comment: Although you've updated your attempt, this won't work still. An employee who joined on `2000-01-01` and has a Left date of `'2018-08-16'` would have been working on `2017-05-31`, however, your query would discount them.

Comment: `GETDATE()` isn't the right answer here either I'm afraid. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would count the employees who are at work as of that date, right? Meaning they should have entered on or BEFORE that day:

```
select count(*)
from employees
where DateOfEntry <= '20170531' and 
      (dateLeft is null OR dateLeft >= '20170531');
```

Note: If you wouldn't accept the person as at work on her\his dateLeft then change >= to >.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the DateLeft column in my question. I have updated the question accordingly. Grateful for an update to your answer.

Comment: @user3115933, edited my answer to take dateLeft into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*),dept from employee where '31-may-2017'>DateOfEntry 
  and '31_-may-2017'<DateOfLeft  group by dept;
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always explain how the problem has been solved and what the code does.